# Why do I always have to switch between expo versions

Tags: react-native, expo

So, I usually code on expo.io, but now I'm a facing a issue with expo versions, whenever I open an expo project on my iPhone I get to see an error - (0, _reactNavigation.createAppContainer) is not a function. (In '(0, _reactNavigation.createAppContainer)(AppSwitchNavigator)', '(0, _reactNavigation.createAppContainer)' is undefined) - but when I change the exo version it works properly, and I have to do it frequently, wehenver I open my project
Please help me out

Comment: Hi I think your question might be better awnsered to the relevant company/organisation's technical support team.
If that is the case the question might be [off-topic (read point 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
However following the base on-topic points:  
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is  
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.
It seems like your question is on-topic

Comment: Not sure if Question is on or off topic